# Why is a semicolon used here instead of a full stop?

Tags: sentence, semicolons

I came across this sentence in the book I'm reading (Enchanter's End Game by David Eddings) and I was wondering why the semicolon is used instead of a full stop.

[image: Image of printed book]

> Unlike the western Grolims Garion had seen in Cthol Murgos, they rarely wore the polished steel mask, but rather assumed a set, grim expression, thin-lipped and narrow-eyed; as they went about the streets in their hooded black robes, everyone, Mallorean and Nadrak alike, gave way to them.

Comment: The sentences are to be treated as connected, that's all. See [here for more](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/169415/15299).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using semicolons to create run-on sentences ... what's the deal with semis?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169404/using-semicolons-to-create-run-on-sentences-whats-the-deal-with-semis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a stylistic choice. Semicolons are generally regarded as interrupting the flow of a passage of text to a lesser degree than periods (full stops to you). Authors often use flow to create a certain rhythm in their work. For example, Ernest Hemingway tended to write lots of short sentences, giving his work a choppy, staccato feel; William Faulkner used long sentences held together with colons and semicolons to create a winding, languid impression.

In the passage above, the "as they went about the streets..." clause refers back to the previous one, so the author used a semicolon to create a single long sentence tying them together.